# remove_if removes element even when predicate returns false?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, std, erase-remove-idiom

I am writing an octree algorithm.
Inside function I traverse octree.
I get node pointer and Sphere as input. I check if node should hold sphere then I want to add it 
to node`s object list and remove it from its parent`s list. following is code

```
functionBody()
{
 .....

  if (!node->objectList.empty())
      node->objectList.erase(std::remove_if(node->objectList.begin(), node->objectList.end()-1 , [&t](auto& temp) { return temp == t; }));

...
}

typedef struct Sphere
{
    Sphere() = default;
    Sphere(const Vector3 centre_, const float radius_, const Material& material_) : centre(centre_), radius(radius_), material(material_)
    {
        assert(radius != 0);
        invRadius = 1.0 / radius;

        Vector3 radiusOffset = Vector3(radius);
        aabb.min = Vector3(centre - radiusOffset);
        aabb.max = Vector3(centre + radiusOffset);
    }

    bool operator==(const Sphere& rhs)
    {
        return (centre == rhs.centre) && (radius == rhs.radius);
    }

    Vector3 centre;
    float radius;
    float invRadius;
    Material material;
    AABB aabb;

}Sphere;
```

As you can see for Sphere I have `operator==` defined.

I see that `remove_if` is removing element even when predicate is returning false.

for example, first iteration it finds one sphere `t` and removed it from parents vector using `remove_if`. This `t` was present at last of vector. consider now parent remains with 3 spheres in its vector but, when I go to other child now we still try to search `t` in parent and `remove_if` still removes last entry. I don't get why?

Comment: `end()-1` is also suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::remove_if` returns the `end` iterator provided when it doesn't find anything to remove. You've given `node->objectList.end()-1` as the end iterator which is an iterator to the last element in `node->objectList`. This is what you pass to `erase` when you don't find `t` so the last element gets erased.

To fix the problem, use the overload of `erase` that takes a range of elements :

```
if (!node->objectList.empty())
{
    auto end_iter = node->objectList.end();
    auto to_remove = std::remove_if(
        node->objectList.begin(), end_iter, 
        [&t](auto& temp) { return temp == t; });

    node->objectList.erase(to_remove, end_iter);
}
```

Now if `t` isn't found `erase` won't do anything at all. In that case, `remove_if` returns `end_iter` and `erase` tried to erase the elements in the empty range defined by `end_iter` and itself.

I'm not sure why you were using `node->objectList.end() - 1`. I'm assuming it was either a mistake or a workaround for the crash that you would otherwise likely get with the previous code.

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling the method erase that accepts only one iterator (not a range of iterators) and the algorithm `std::remove_if` is called with the second iterator of the range of container elements specified like

```
node->objectList.end()-1
```

then even if the element is not found in the container the algorithm `remove_if` will return the iterator `node->objectList.end()-1` that points to a valid object in the container. This object will be erased from the container.

Here is a demonstrative program that reproduces the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    while ( v.size() > 1 )
    {
        v.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin( v ), std::prev( std::end( v ) ),
                                 []( const auto &item )
                                 { 
                                    return item % 2 == 0; 

                                 } ) );
    }

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 3 5 7 9 
1
```

That is none element in the vector is an even number. Nevertheless all elements except one were erased from the vector.

It seems that you are incorrectly specifying the range. It should be specified like a pair

```
node->objectList.begin(), node->objectList.end()
```

Or before erasing an element you should check whether the returned iterator is equal to `node->objectList.end() - 1` (provided that you indeed want to use the range shown in your question). In this case the method erase should not be called. Or you should specify an erased range of iterators like

```
if (!node->objectList.empty())
      node->objectList.erase(std::remove_if(node->objectList.begin(), node->objectList.end()-1 , [&t](auto& temp) { return temp == t; }).
                             node->objectList.end()-1);
```

Again provided that you indeed want to use the second iterator of the range like `node->objectList.end()-1` instead of `node->objectList.end()`.